# jQuery Set the Value of Input Box

Tags: jquery, html, forms, business-catalyst

I am pretty new to jQuery and I am having issue with setting an input text box to a default value. I have tried using the val method and also the .attr method. Neither seem to work. I will post my input html and both jQuery that I have tried below. I am going to guess I have a syntax issue. I did try a couple of the answers posted on other questions and I couldn't seem to get it to work. Thanks for any help.

```
<input id="DiscountCode" class="discountcodeInput" type="text" name="DiscountCode"
value="" onchange="ApplyDiscountCode(this.value,3460847,209327);return false;"></input>
<input class="update" type="button" value="Update" onclick="return false;"></input>
```

jQuery:

Current:

```
$(document).load(function(){
    $('input#DiscountCode.discountcodeInput').val('SANFORDSUITES');
});
```

Have tried this also:

```
$(document).load(function(){
    $('input#DiscountCode.discountcodeInput').attr('value', 'SANFORDSUITES');
});
```

Comment: By the way, there's no such thing as a closing `</input>` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you want `$(document).ready(function(){... })`, rather than `.load()`.

Comment: Thank you that seemed to do it.